# How to skip data points in bokeh plot?

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, skip

Consider the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

output_file("plot_dates.html")

p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime')

data = dict(
    dates=[dt(2015, 1, 1), dt(2015, 1, 2), dt(2015, 1, 3)],
    values=[1,2,3])
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

p.line('dates', 'values', source=source)

show(p)
```

This displays a line correcty.
If now I want to skip a point, e.g. the second I had hoped that setting an element either in `dates` or in `values` (or in both), would result in a point being skipped. 
Unfortunately, that is not the case, but `None` is displayed as it was "0", which translates to 1970-01-01 in the case of the dates. Is there a simple way to skip data or must this be done by hand (or through a separate library)?

I know this could be done more or less easily using `pandas` for filtering out the rows/columns containing `None` elements, but I cannot use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you mean, you can do this with `NaN` values, not `None`. But you will have to use NumPy, both for `np.nan` and also to ensure that the arrays are properly encoded to be able to transmit `NaN` values into the browser.

Additionally, you'll need more points. When line data has a `NaN` value in it, the segments on *both* sides are skipped, so with only three points, nothing will be drawn at all, because there are no complete segments anywhere. With five points you can see:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime as dt
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

output_file("plot_dates.html")

p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime')

data = dict(
    dates=[dt(2015, 1, 1), dt(2015, 1, 2), dt(2015, 1, 3), dt(2015, 1, 4), dt(2015, 1, 5)],
    values=np.array([1.0, 3.0, np.nan, 5.0, 4.0]))
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

p.line('dates', 'values', source=source)

show(p)
```

[image]

EDIT: This could also be accomplished with a `CDSView` without needing to put any `NaN` values in:

```
view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[IndexFilter([0, 1, 3, 4])]) 
p.line('dates', 'values', source=source, view=view)
```

It's not clear from your question what you mean by "skip" though. If you mean is there a way to draw the line simply as if the point was not there at all, i.e. without the interruption above that `NaN` or a filter gives, then the answer is "no". You will need to pre-filter your data.

Comment: Upvoted, but does not show up. That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Why not just delete the data you don't want? It doesn't require any package

```
data = dict(dates=[dt(2015, 1, 1), dt(2015, 1, 2), dt(2015, 1, 3)], values=[1,2,3])

# remove the 1st date 
dates2 = data['dates']
values2 = data['values']
del dates2[1]
del values2[1]
data2 = dict(dates=dates2,values=values2) 
# this should be the dict from before without the 1st date and 1st value
```

You could write a function to delete the nth date.

```
def deldate(n,data):

    dates2 = data['dates']
    values2 = data['values']
    del dates2[n]
    del values2[n]
    data2 = dict(dates=dates2,values=values2) 
    return data2
```

Comment: This answer is bad in two ways: (1) this is precisely what OP is trying to avoid; (2) even in such cases, deleting the point is just a very rough way of doing so, and masking after conversion to Numpy array would be a much cleaner approach.